React Js , Unit Test Case ... For Idle timer set up for inactivity. React js Test cases for hooks and states and useefeects
`1. When Mock Data with timeou enabled and different timing --- then timeout enabled
2. When Mock Data timeout disabled --- then timeout value same & should not updated
3. SetRemaining function called testing
4. URL Logout called on Idle time
5. URL logout function do not called when timeout disabled

    const handleOnActive = () => {
        console.log("Setting Active")
        setStatus('Active');
    };

    const handleOnAction = () => {
        console.log("Setting Count")
        setCount(count + 1);
    };

    const { getRemainingTime } = useIdleTimer({
        timeout: timeoutValue * 60 * 1000,
        onIdle: handleOnIdle,
        onActive: handleOnActive,
        onAction: handleOnAction,
        debounce: 250
    });


    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log('inside the use effect to set timer', isTimeoutEnabled)
        if (isTimeoutEnabled) {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                console.log("setRemaining --------", remaining);
                setRemaining(Math.ceil(getRemainingTime() / 1000));
            }, 1000);

            return () => {
                clearInterval(interval);
            };
        }
    }, [timeoutValue, isTimeoutEnabled]);


`


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
